# How do i GROUP BY or DISTINCT inside array?

Tags: php, sql, select, distinct

I have searched high and low and cant find a similar issue to what i have.

I am a beginner so please forgive my clunky query structure.

I am trying to ( have attached screen grab below of output ):

- Query the **photos table** to get the id based on category id and also start,limit because of pagination.
- Query the **photos tagged table** based on the photo id i just got from the first query.

But my problem is that i cant group the tags, some photos have the same tag name. And the output just shows all the tags for each photo. I want **restaurant** to show only once etc...

```
<?php
  // Get the file ideez and dont go beyond pagination start,limit eg:30,10       
$queryFile = "SELECT id FROM $tableName WHERE cat_id=".$fileID."  LIMIT $start, $limit";
$resultFile = mysql_query($queryFile);

while ($rowFile = mysql_fetch_array($resultFile)) { 
    // Get the tag names based on the file ideez retrived from the above query   
    $queryTagged = "SELECT tag_name FROM photoTagged WHERE file_id=".$rowFile['id']." GROUP BY tag_name";
    $resultTagged = mysql_query($queryTagged) or die(mysql_error()); 
    while ($rowTagged = mysql_fetch_array($resultTagged)) { 
        $tagged = $rowTagged['tag_name'];
        ?>
        <li><a href="#"><?php echo $tagged; ?></li>
<?php }} ?>
```

***the above query is producing:***

> bar,cappucino,coffee,coffee machine,restaurant,bar,cappucino,coffee,coffee machine,restaurant,bar,coffee,restaurant,bar,coffee,coffee machine
>       restaurant,bar,cappucino,coffee,restaurant

***what i need to show is:***

> bar,cappucino,coffee,coffee machine,restaurant

If anyone could help i would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you in advance.

John

---

My new code is

```
<?php
  // Get the file ideez and dont go beyond pagination start,limit eg:30,10       
$queryFile = "SELECT id FROM $tableName WHERE cat_id=".$fileID."  LIMIT $start, $limit";
$resultFile = mysql_query($queryFile);

while ($rowFile = mysql_fetch_array($resultFile)) { 
    // Get the tag names based on the file ideez retrived from the above query   
    $queryTagged = "SELECT DISTINCT tag_name FROM photoTagged WHERE file_id=".$rowFile['id'];
    $resultTagged = mysql_query($queryTagged) or die(mysql_error()); 
    $rowTagged = mysql_fetch_array($resultTagged);
    $tagged = $rowTagged['tag_name'];

    ?>
    <li><a href="#"><?php echo $tagged; ?></li>
<?php } ?>
```

I now get this: ( So i am close arent i? )

```
----------
cappucino
restaurant
bar
coffee machine
restaurant
coffee

coffee





restaurant
restaurant
restaurant
coffee
coffee
restaurant
restaurant
coffee machine
restaurant
coffee
```

I wonder if the spaces are something? i got that from copy and paste...

Any further help would be appreciated :-)

Comment: The sample code might be vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html), which is a very serious [security risk](http://bobby-tables.com/). To fix this hole, switch from the outdated mysql driver to [PDO](http://php.net/PDO) and use [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/PDO.prepared-statements). If you need a PDO tutorial, try ["Writing MySQL Scripts with PHP and PDO"](http://www.kitebird.com/articles/php-pdo.html). The site you save may just be your own.

Comment: Indeed this code is begging to be exploited. But the OP will probably not be swapping this code with PDO anytime soon (otherwise he 'd be already using PDO). So, a more practical and easy to adopt suggestion: *please* wrap all your $id variables in `intval`, e.g. `cat_id='.intval($fileID)`.

Comment: Thank you outis, i am yet to do realescapes and clean it up a little. the code runs inside a password prottected admin as well. That is used by people who wouldnt know the diff between mysql and myspace. But i will read up on PDO - it looks a little out of my league though. Got some simple example code on how to make secure connection, query and result?

Comment: outis's last link looks good.

Comment: trust me on this: you can't trust users. One might come along who knows what zhe's doing, or someone else might break into their account, or some user's computer might get infected by a [worm](http://www.google.com/search?q=worm+SQL+injection) (there are a not insignificant number that exploit SQL injection). Security needs to be present right from the start of the design process, not an afterthought or a secondary feature. I find PDO is a little simpler to use than the old mysql driver. [Query results](http://php.net/PDOStatement) are [traversable](http://php.net/Traversable), for one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to do a sub-query to dodge the pagination problems with the photos. If you wish the selected tags to be a subset of the photos found in your first query, then you will need to do the following.

```
<?php 
   $queryTagged = "SELECT TAG.tag_name, count(TAG.tag_name) AS num FROM photoTagged as TAG JOIN (SELECT id FROM $tableName WHERE cat_id=$fileID LIMIT $start, $limit) as PHOTO ON (PHOTO.id = TAG.file_id) GROUP BY TAG.tag_name"; 
   $resultTagged = mysql_query($queryTagged) or die(mysql_error());  

   while ($tagged = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultTagged)) {
      echo "<li id="'.$tagged['TAG.tag_name'].'"><a href="#">".$tagged['TAG.tag_name']." (".$tagged['TAG.num'].")</li>";
   }
?>
```

This way you will have two queries, on for finding the photos, and one for finding the tags for the photos on that page. This technically takes a little longer as MySQL has to load the query into a temporary table, but it should work fine.

Comment: Thank you Ghostpsalm it worked a treat! Merry Christmas and happy new year :-)

Answer (score 2):

You should first perform a join between your photos and tags table, and THEN select the distinct tags.

I believe this query will let the database do all the work for you:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tag_name
FROM (SELECT file_id FROM $tableName WHERE cat_id=$fileID LIMIT $start, $limit) t1
LEFT JOIN photoTagged ON t1.id = photoTagged.file_id
```

You can also sort the tags in the database (`ORDER BY tag_name`).

Haven't tried it myself, so maybe the syntax is a bit off. But the idea should work.

Comment: +1 for joining. Not only will it give the desired result, it's much more efficient. There's no good reason for multiple queries when one will do.

Comment: Thanks Jon, i havent tried yours but i'll keep it in the kitty. John v's worked for me and i tried it first. Thanks for your time

Comment: I spoke too soon, im trying your query Jon

Answer (score 1):

distinct doesnt work if you are only getting one record at a time, so put the data in a PHP array and then use array_unique, which is PHPs way to do  distinct

```
   <?php 
        // Get the file ideez and dont go beyond pagination start,limit eg:30,10        

        $queryFile = "SELECT id FROM $tableName WHERE cat_id=".$fileID."  LIMIT $start, $limit"; 
        $resultFile = mysql_query($queryFile); 
        while ($rowFile = mysql_fetch_array($resultFile)) {  

        // Get the tag names based on the file ideez retrived from the above query    

        $queryTagged = "SELECT tag_name FROM photoTagged WHERE file_id=".$rowFile['id']; 
        $resultTagged = mysql_query($queryTagged) or die(mysql_error());  
        $rowTagged = mysql_fetch_array($resultTagged) 
        $tagged[] = $rowTagged['tag_name']; 
    }
// Let PHP do the work.
     $tagged=array_unique($tagged);
    while (list(,$val) = each($tagged)) {
        echo "<li><a href="#">$val</li> 
     }
      ?>
```

Comment: Hi John,

That was freakishly easy! wow! thanks man! can i buy you a coffee?

It all works great and i think i get it too, so thats important :-).

Comment: Oh yeah and i pressed the enter key too quick. The one thing it does is add a li at the bottom the contains not tag?

Comment: Hey John,

the empty li is because one photo has no tags at all. How do i tell it to ignore untagged photos. I will brainstorm in the mean time anyways. Also am serious about buying you a coffee ( Got a button on a website? )

Comment: Actually when i double checked the tags associated with each photo i noticed its not showing me all the tags.

For example photo id=293 has coffee,cappuccino,smile

But i am only getting coffee from that photo?

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT DISTINCT tag_name FROM photoTagged WHERE file_id=".$rowFile['id']` ?

Comment: Hi Diogo, i wish that worked. I should have said that i tried that too. It looks to me like i am trying to group tag names, but the query produces only one of each anyway ( per photo id i mean ).

Comment: by the way, you have a while inside another while. you may be getting the result from more than one photo or something. Also, the group by groups the results (equals comes in sequence). you should use distinct

Comment: Ok cool, thanks Diogo, i think i nearly have it with your help.

Comment: Hey Diogo i have edited my post with the code chage you said and its producing less tags but the results are still a bit weird.

Comment: well, i'd need to see more code and some date from database (from both tables)... try running those querys directly on your database and follow the logic of the algorithm, does it show to right output ?

Comment: Diogo, i think i got it from John V's code. Thank you for being the first to respond and thank you for your time.